# Access jinja2 templates from a folder outside of package

Tags: python, jinja2, weasyprint

I'm trying to generate bills in pdf with Weasyprint and Jinja2
I have the following file structure:

```
project  
  scripts  
     pdf_builder.py  
  templates  
    bill_template.html  
    bill_style.css
```

However, whatever I try I get the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: ../templates/bill_template.html

My relevant code for `pdf_builder.py` is:

```
from weasyprint import HTML
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

file_html = "../templates/bill_template.html"

# loading the jinja2 environment
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('../templates'))

# Render and build
template = env.get_template(file_html)
html_out = template.render()
HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf(pdf_name, stylesheets=[file_css])
```

- Is it actually impossible to access templates from a folder outside of the current folder with jinja?
- Or did I get the paths all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

For jinja, you need to specify in the `FileSystemLoader` where the templates folder is, and then give the relative paths to the template file from that.

But, for the css (that you give to Weasyprint, you have to to specify the relative path from the working directory).

That gives:

```
file_html = f"{document_type}_template.html"
file_css = f"templates/{document_type}_style.css"

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
template = env.get_template(file_html)
html_out = template.render(template_vars)
HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf(pdf_name, stylesheets=[file_css])
```